# Values for which tetration to infinite heights (i.e., $x^{x^{x^{x^{.^{.^{.}}}}}}$) converges

Tags: real-analysis

I was reading [Evaluating tetration to infinite heights (e.g., $2^{2^{2^{2^{.^{.^.}}}}}$)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/362356/). For what values of $x$ does tetration to infinite heights  (i.e., $x^{x^{x^{x^{.^{.^{.}}}}}}$) converge?

Comment: what do you think?

Comment: Note that such a number $x=t^{t^{t^{.^{.^.}}}}$ (if it exists) will necessarily lie at a point of intersection of $y=x$ and $y=t^x$.

Comment: You express your expression in terms of the Lambert $W$ function as $ y={x^{x^{x^{.^{.^{.}}}}}} \implies y = -\frac{W(-\ln(x))}{\ln(x)} $

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look up "exponential tower" or "tetration".
Calculating the expression
involves Lambert's famous $W$ function
with a value of
$\frac{W(-\ln x)}{-\ln x}$.

Wikipedia has a nice discussion at
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration.

As shown there,
your expression converges for
$e^{-e} \le x \le e^{1/e}$.
As with at least 50% of the
questions proposed here,
this was shown by Euler.

Comment: +1 :) Could you explain a bit about how you got to $e^{-e} \le x \le e^{1/e}$?

Comment: It's in the Wikipedia article, a little ways in.

Comment: strange bound.  thanks.

Comment: I think Lambert functions explains the tetration's convergence very well. thanks.

Comment: I see where the Wikipedia article states this interval, but I don't see where the article shows it.