# Limits of tetrations of infinite height

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, tetration

[We know that](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/362418/28900) tetrations of infinite height converge for $x$ such that  $e^{-e} \le x \le e^{1/e}$. Which real numbers are limits of some tetration of infinite height? what is the complete set of such limits? thanks.